# CodeLite wont detect my (Installed) MinGW32 Compiler, so is there another way to locate it

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, mingw32, codelite

**I have a 32-Bit Windows 7, and dont have plans to change it**
I do have an installed Compiler that I installed on my desktop because it says do not isnstall it in a folder with spaces in it.. I manually did configure CodeLite, but the compiler doesn't show up, I followed all the links Codelite tells you to visit to download MinGW, so how do I locate the new compiler in CodeLite? Is there another way?

**I Manually configured CodeLite**
I manually tried to configure CodeLite to use the MinGW compiler for 32-Bit devices, and expected it to show up in `Settings > Build Settings > Compilers` but it didn't.

So my question is how do I "tell" the editor where the compiler is located? I tried doing it by going to `Settings > Build Settings > Add Compiler Button` but it didn't work so why doesn't it work or if there is another way please tell me.

Comment: And what's your actual question?

Comment: @JesperJuhl yeah I did edit it, and said is there another way to locate the compiler

Comment: @GhulamMuhammad You followed some instructions that should have located the compiler. You really should be asking why those instructions didn't work instead of asking if there is another way. I don't know anything about CodeLite so I can't really help with that.

Comment: @GhulamMuhammad I agree with the previous comment, you are trying to do too much at once. I'm not going to say install Linux, but I will say that before you try to get CodeLite working you should make sure that the MinGW compiler is working by itself. Obviously the compiler is not going to work from CodeLite if you have made some mistake installing the compiler itself. Since you are working with old hardware and software there are a lot of things that could be wrong.

Comment: You may want to start with  using msys2 to install MinGW: [https://www.msys2.org/#installation](https://www.msys2.org/#installation)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik There is nothing challenging (for an experienced developer) about opening IDE settings and pasting a compiler path into them. If that's too hard for somebody who calls himself an "experienced developer", I have bad news for him. I'd understand if the question was about some mingw-specific DLL hell (which isn't hard to fix either), but this is just minimal IDE configuration, come on.

Comment: You should add more details. Ok, you pressed "Add Compiler", in what way that "didn't work"?

Comment: @drescherjm It works, I installed MinGW using msys2 and I discovered I was using a pirated version of the compiler... Thanks, now I shall continue my journey.

Comment: Great! I think msys2 is the best way to get an up to date and working MinGW on windows. In addition the package management is very good and removes the need to download binaries (which may be incompatible with your toolchain) or build from source which may not always work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and using msys2 to install MinGW is a great idea!

Answer (score 0):

I should Install [msys2](https://www.msys2.org/#installation), as said by [@drescherjm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487892/drescherjm)
edit: IT WORKS! Thx to [@drescherjm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487892/drescherjm)!

Comment: Did you actually try it? I'm not sure if they still support win 7.

Comment: Yes I will in the morning.. Its night time and I'm on mobile @HolyBlackCat